# Appending keyword None to sublists in lists

Tags: list, python-3.x, append

I want to append keyword None to the list.

1. If the number of elements in the input list
   is less than rows*columns then fill the two dimensional list with the keyword None.
2. If the number of elements in the input list is larger than rows*columns
   then ignore the extra elements.

For the input given `try_convert_1D_to_2D([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 4)` I would like to achieve something like this: `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None]]`

What I tried is:

```
def try_convert_1D_to_2D(my_list, r, c):
    a=r*c
    b=len(my_list)
    if(b >= a):
        l=[my_list[i:i+c] for i in range(0,b,c)]
        return l[0:r]
    else:
        for i in range(0,b,c):
            k=my_list[i:i+c]
            return [k.append(None) for k in a]
```

For the input

```
try_convert_1D_to_2D([8, 2, 9, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7, 10], 2, 3)
```

I could achieve `[[8, 2, 9],[4, 1, 6]]` which is correct.

Can someone please enlighten me where I am doing wrong and please suggest me how best I can do. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the results you're getting that don't match expectations.

Comment: For the record, using `k.append(None)` in the listcomp is almost certainly causing problems; `list.append` doesn't return the `list`, it just returns `None`, so that listcomp is just returning a `list` equivalent to what you'd get if you did `[None] * len(a)`. The listcomp is also overriding/ignoring the `k` you defined just one line earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pointed out [several issues in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763378/appending-keyword-none-to-sublists-in-lists/35763537#comment59199625_35763378), here is a version that actually works:

```
def try_convert_1D_to_2D(my_list, r, c):
    # Pad with Nones to necessary length
    padded = my_list + [None] * max(0, (r * c - len(my_list)))
    # Slice out rows at a time in a listcomp until we have what we need
    return [padded[i:i+c] for i in range(0, r*c, c)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and also correcting mistake in code.